# Несколько роутов на странице....

Tags: php, php-frameworks, kohana

Читаю статью http://kohanaframework.su/advanced/route_p1 .Увидел код:

```
  Route::set('about', 'about')
        ->defaults(array(
                'controller' => 'static',
                'action'     => 'about',
        ));

    Route::set('cont', 'cont')
        ->defaults(array(
                'controller' => 'static',
                'action'     => 'contacts',
        ));
```

-Вопрос зачем несколько роутеров??

Пишут что если перейти по адресу **сайт/cont** то будет вызван  'controller' => 'static' и метод 'action'     => 'contacts' .
Но у меня Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL cont was not found on this server.

Контроллер static и метод contacts созданы.

Comment: > The requested URL **cont** was not found on this server

``cont``, а ``action`` установлен ``contacts``  
Метод должен называться ``action_contacts``, а не ``contacts``

Comment: "Метод (в контроллере) должен называться action_contacts, а не contacts "--он так и записан..Все методы контроллера идут с этим префиксом .

Comment: Спасибо разобрался...Последним должен итди default Request а перед ним все другие,иначе работать не будет...

Comment: Да, всё верно. От более конкретных к более общим, т.к. роутер остановится на первом подходящем.